# How to save image in a file?

Tags: php, image

On my page I use a script to get a new image:

```
    $targ_w = $targ_h = 150;
    $jpeg_quality = 90;

    $src = $_POST['image'];
    $img_r = imagecreatefromjpeg($src);
    $dst_r = ImageCreateTrueColor( $targ_w, $targ_h );

    imagecopyresampled($dst_r,$img_r,0,0,$_POST['x'],$_POST['y'],
    $targ_w,$targ_h,$_POST['w'],$_POST['h']);

    header('Content-type: image/jpeg');
    imagejpeg($dst_r,null,$jpeg_quality);
```

Currently, the script receives $_POST data, extracts an image from it, then displays that image back to the user.

Now I would like to add logic to save the image in a file, but I don't know how to go about it. Any hints will be appreciated.

Comment: pass a filename into the second parameter of imagejpeg.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need:

```
imagejpeg($dst_r, "filename", $jpeg_quality);
```

---

Check the manual of [`imagejpeg()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagejpeg.php).

```
bool imagejpeg ( resource $image [, string $filename [, int $quality ]] )
```

> **`filename`**
>
> The path to save the file to. If not set or NULL, the raw image stream will be outputted directly.
>
> To skip this argument in order to provide the quality parameter, use NULL.

Answer (score 0):

`imagejpeg()` takes an optional filename to save the jpeg to file:

```
imagejpeg($image, "/path/to/file" . $name);
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagejpeg.php

Answer (score 0):

Just specify the location rather than NULL

```
imagejpeg($strImage, <NEW LOCATION>, 100);
```

Answer (score 0):

`imagejpeg($dst_r,'/path/to/file/new.jpg',$jpeg_quality);`